# How to compute a covariance matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, statistics, covariance

this question seems surprisingly obscure...I asked google before posting it here and the closest thing I found that resemble an answer is this : [Covariance matrix computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307082/covariance-matrix-computation)

However I am not sure of the answer, from the comments.

What would be the best way to correctly compute a covariance matrix in C#?

Any good free library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the [AlgLib library](http://www.alglib.net/) which looks promising.

It has a function to calculate covariance matrix :

```
public static void covm(double[,] x, out double[,] c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use EmguCV which C# wrapper for OpenCV library.Something like this

```
CvInvoke.cvCallcCovarMatrix();
```