# C++ PCA - Calculating covariance MATRIX

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, covariance

I'm trying to calculate the Covariance (matrix) of a vector in C++ ...

I have carried out the following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > data = { {2.5, 2.4}, {0.5, 0.7} };
```

I have then calculated and subtracted the mean, which gave the following result:

```
data = { {0.05, -0.05}, {-0.1, 0.1} }
```

As far as I'm aware, the next step is to transpose the matrix, and multiply the origin together, take the sum and finally divide by the dimensions X - 1..

I have written the following:

```
void cover(std::vector<std::vector<double> > &d)
{
    double cov = 0.0; 

    for(unsigned i=0; (i < d.size()); i++)
    {
        for(unsigned j=0; (j < d[i].size()); j++)
        {
            cov += d[i][j] * d[j][i] / (d[i].size() - 1);
            std::cout << cov << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Where `d` is the vector after the mean has been subtracted from each of the points 
Which gives me the result:

```
0.0025, 0.0075 
0.0125, 0.0225
```

Where compared with matlab:

```
2.0000    1.7000
1.7000    1.4450
```

Does anyone have any ideas to where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you go through the steps in the algorithm with pencil and paper do you get the Matlab results? If no, fix the algorithm. If yes, debug step by step and see when the program's results differ from the pencil and paper results.

Comment: Why don't you use a library for matrix algebra, such as Eigen? The code would be much shorter and easier on the eyes. You will probably need a library for calculating the eigenvectors, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement:

> As far as I'm aware, the next step is to transpose the matrix, and multiply the origin together, take the sum and finally divide by the dimensions X - 1..

And this implementation:

```
cov += d[i][j] * d[j][i] / (d[i].size() - 1);
```

Don't say the same thing. Based on the definition [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section5/pmc541.htm):

```
void outer_product(vector<double> row, vector<double> col, vector<vector<double>>& dst) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < col.size(); i++) {
            dst[i][j] = row[i] * col[j];
        }
    }
}

//computes row[i] - val for all i;
void subtract(vector<double> row, double val, vector<double>& dst) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
        dst[i] = row[i] - val;
    }
}

//computes m[i][j] + m2[i][j]
void add(vector<vector<double>> m, vector<vector<double>> m2, vector<vector<double>>& dst) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < m[i].size(); j++) { 
            dst[i][j] = m[i][j] + m2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

double mean(std::vector<double> &data) {
    double mean = 0.0;

    for(unsigned i=0; (i < data.size());i++) {
        mean += data[i];
    }

    mean /= data.size();
    return mean;
}

void scale(vector<vector<double>> & d, double alpha) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < d.size(); i++) {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < d[i].size(); j++) {
            d[i][j] *= alpha;
        }
    }
}
```

So, given these definitions, we can compute the value for the covariance matrix.

```
void compute_covariance_matrix(vector<vector<double>> & d, vector<vector<double>> & dst) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < d.size(); i++) {
        double y_bar = mean(d[i]);
        vector<double> d_d_bar(d[i].size());
        subtract(d[i], y_bar, d_d_bar);
        vector<vector<double>> t(d.size());
        outer_product(d_d_bar, d_d_bar, t);
        add(dst, t, dst);
    } 
    scale(dst, 1/(d.size() - 1));
}
```

Comment: @aacomar - Hey thanks, but this didn't work. I don't see why you do `cov = (cov + d`..?

Comment: The order you specified the operations was take the sum then finally divide by the dimensions X - 1. The way you had it, the sum was updated with the value *after* division. And I'm aware that it's not the only necessary fix, the algorithm itself doesn't work.

Comment: Ahh, this question is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307082/covariance-matrix-computation . Check there and see if it answers your question.

Comment: If you look here though: https://github.com/liyanghua/Principal-component-analysis-/blob/master/pca.cpp#L90 this is doing what I'm doing.. I just can't figure out why I'm getting such wrong results.

Comment: Ahh, that's a totally different beast. I'll fix my answer to correspond with that.

Comment: Note that the algorithm you linked computes a single scalar covariance for the matrix and not a matrix covariance the way Matlab does. If you want the latter, check my previous link.

Comment: Ok, noticed that your link also includes the calculation for a covariance_matrix as the very next function. I updated my answer to reflect that code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51461/discussion-between-user1326876-and-acomar)

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe For loop in *outer_product* it's wrong:

```
void outer_product(vector<double> row, vector<double> col, vector<vector<double>>& dst) {
for(unsigned i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
    for(unsigned j = 0; j < col.size(); i++) {
        dst[i][j] = row[i] * col[j];
    }
}
```

I will change **i++   ->   j++**